# Why does optimizer estimate 1 row for this plan?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, optimization

Here's my plan I'm having trouble with: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r168tltbe

I'm betting this is something easy I'm not seeing. I have a query that is running very slowly because instead of the optimizer pulling in the 16 rows from the 'child' table, it says "pull all the rows from the child table between 26550557 and 28078855".  I rebuilt the statistics on the index, which worked in one of my environments, but not another.

```
RANGE_HI_KEY    RANGE_ROWS  EQ_ROWS DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS AVG_RANGE_ROWS
26461290        32767       1       16043               2.042449
26652512        65544       1       31523               2.079244
26868906        65535       1       31715               2.066372
26950626        32765       4       15484               2.116055
27097668        32762       6       16202               2.022096
27220249        32810       4       15978               2.053448
27301782        32770       1       15161               2.161467
27572159        32782       4       15406               2.127872
27758980        32793       4       16564               1.979775
27864880        32781       4       16356               2.004219
27922320        32771       4       16075               2.038631
28092976        32789       5       16462               1.991799
```

You can see from my DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS partial results above, there is more than 1 row in that range.

EDIT: Posted correct range of stats (per Martin) and a non-commented query.  *Thanks everyone for your responses!*

EDIT2: Here's the stats_stream.  Also, even though is says sorting is 44% of the effort, removing that sort speeds it up by a negligible amount.  Because stats_stream is so large, here's a link to it:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6gu1jvb1q7tg8/Stats_Stream.csv?dl=0

EDIT3: DDL Script - https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6gu1jvb1q7tg8/Stats_Stream.csv?dl=0

Comment: Can't see the whole query. What happens if you break the subquery out into a table variable, or temp table, then query that?

Comment: Please remove the commented lines and post another plan or provide the query text in your question.

Comment: the part of the histogram you have shown us ends at 26.2mn. Your query looks at a range starting at 26.5mn

Comment: To add to what Martin has said, this is called an ascending key problem - the range you are searching is outside the bounds that the current stats knows about. Try updating stats again, perhaps using FULLSCAN, until your RANGE_HI_KEY bumps.

Comment: Nic, if I take the 16 numbers in the IN statement and put them in a temp table and then inner join to that table, it runs quickly.  Not an option in production because the query comes from entity framework.

Comment: I have a few ideas but want to poke around a bit. Can you provide the stats_stream for your statistics object along with the column datatype? Use DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS WITH STATS_STREAM; That'll let us reproduce your issue in our databases.

Comment: This is more complicated than I thought. I suspect that this is an issue with join cardinality estimates. It's not clear to me if there is a statistics issue on one or both tables. Can you provide the table and index DDL for both tables? Can you also provide the stats stream output for PK_parent_plan and IDX_child_plan_Search? I think that you already provided IDX_child_plan_Search but it's important to label it and to give the table DDL. Otherwise SQL Server will say that the STATS_STREAM is corrupt when I try to use it.

Comment: Darn.  I renamed the table, columns, and indexes before posting.  I should have known STATS_STREAM would not work!  I'll try to replicate the situation using the fake names and generate STATS_STREAM from that.  Sorry I didn't think of that sooner.

Comment: As far as I can tell the column and table names don't match. I just need to have the right datatypes for everything.

Comment: Thx Joe.  I've updated the stats_stream file in dropbox and added DDL files.  I inserted data from the original table where parent_plan < 26206985, then created the indexes, then inserted the rest of the data.  I got similar results and I pulled stats_stream.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fq6gu1jvb1q7tg8/Stats_Stream.csv?dl=0

I concur, it's something other than the IDX_child_plan_Search index stats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48622/discussion-between-joe-obbish-and-j-brune).